# "Error: No such file or directory" for input that has to be generated first

Tags: snakemake

I have two rules for STAR, STAR_genome does some indexing for the STAR rule, therefore the input of STAR is the direct output from STAR_genome - so far so simple. But when I try to run this, the STAR_genome rule is ignored (not listed in job count) and I get the following exception:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[...]STAR/cauliflower/genome/genome.ok'

I don't understand why snakemake would ignore the generating rule and just complain about a missing file instead, as it even takes the path from the very rule that should generate it...

```
rule STAR_genome:
    input: genome=lambda wildcards: config[wildcards.species]["genomefile"]
    output: ok=path.join(STAR_DIR, "{species}", "genome", "genome.ok")
    threads: 32
    envmodules:
        config["STAR"][0],
        config["STAR"][1]
    script:
        "scripts/Trinity_GG/STAR_genome.py"

############################################################################

rule STAR:
    input:
         genome=rules.STAR_genome.output.ok,
         r1=rules.trim_galore.output.r1,
         r2=rules.trim_galore.output.r2
    output:
        bam=path.join(STAR_DIR, "{species}_{rep}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam")
    threads: 32
    envmodules:
        config["STAR"][0],
        config["STAR"][1]
    script:
        "scripts/Trinity_GG/STAR.py"
```

And here is the full traceback, just in case it could help.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/__init__.py", line 751, in snakemake
    keepmetadata=keep_metadata,
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/workflow.py", line 1000, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 444, in schedule
    run = self.job_selector(needrun)
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 731, in job_selector_greedy
    c = list(map(self.job_reward, jobs))  # job rewards
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 814, in job_reward
    input_size = job.inputsize
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/jobs.py", line 378, in inputsize
    self._inputsize = sum(f.size for f in self.input)
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/jobs.py", line 378, in <genexpr>
    self._inputsize = sum(f.size for f in self.input)
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/io.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/io.py", line 254, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/io.py", line 553, in size
    return self.size_local
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/io.py", line 558, in size_local
    self.check_broken_symlink()
  File "/cluster/easybuild/broadwell/software/mflow/0.0-foss-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake-5.27.4-py3.7.egg/snakemake/io.py", line 563, in check_broken_symlink
    if not self.exists_local and os.lstat(self.file):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[...]/Cauliflower_Test/STAR/cauliflower/genome/genome.ok'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of command snakemake --debug-dag I found that I had an error in the config call at

```
input: genome=lambda wildcards: config[wildcards.species]["genomefile"]
```

The right name was "genome_file" which was mentioned nowhere, but the debug-dag stated:

```
    candidate job STAR
    wildcards: species=cauliflower, rep=A
    file [...]/Cauliflower_Test/Alignmentscores/cauliflower_align_rate.txt:
    No producers found, but file is present on disk.
    Error:
      KeyError: 'genomefile'
    Wildcards:
      species=cauliflower
    Traceback:
      File "[...]/workflows/Trinity_GG.smk", line 9, in <lambda>
```

Hope this helps someone else, it costed me some hours and a lot of nerves...